Dictionary of Mechanical Engineering Part Feature Vocabulary
Anyone know of a good Dictionary/ Compendium of the technical names of Mechanical Engineering part features?
EG. Standoff, Draft Angle, Truss, Axle Bore, Pivot, Etc.
I'm an inventor and I'm designing one of my inventions in CAD using parametric modeling and I continually rack my brain trying to come up with meaningful names for the parametric features.

Perhaps start with some of the books about technical drawing. Then also books like Mechanics of Machines.

There is no known way to have systematic names for everything. This is a huge problem because it makes seatching for components hard and the losses in productivity is in tens of billions.
